# Total number of kits required if 1 batsman need N bats and there are A batsmans

Tags: python-3.x

Tried with if else statement ,if the total number of bats are completely divisible by 4 then bats will be total bats divide by 4. if not completely divisible then 1 more kit will be required

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.